# php imagettftext letter spacing

Tags: php, gd, imagettftext

Does anybody have a function that draws a ttf string (imagettftext) with specified letter spacing?

I cannot find any build-in GD function so I think that it should be done letter by letter adding some constant width.

Maybe someone have such function already :)

ps. the best font will be arial.ttf

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
function imagettftextSp($image, $size, $angle, $x, $y, $color, $font, $text, $spacing = 0)
{        
    if ($spacing == 0)
    {
        imagettftext($image, $size, $angle, $x, $y, $color, $font, $text);
    }
    else
    {
        $temp_x = $x;
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++)
        {
            $bbox = imagettftext($image, $size, $angle, $temp_x, $y, $color, $font, $text[$i]);
            $temp_x += $spacing + ($bbox[2] - $bbox[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

and the call:

```
imagettftextSp($image, 30, 0, 30, 30, $black, 'arial.ttf', $text, 23);
```

Function parameters order meets standard imagettftext parameters order, and the last parameter is optional $spacing parameter. If not set or the passed value is 0, the kerning / letter spacing is not set.

Comment: replace $text[$i] with mb_substr($text, $i, 1) to overcome trouble with mulitibyte characters

Comment: While I appreciate the efforts, I don't think this function is robust enough. It mangles the letter spacing when its iterated through like that. See for yourself. Compare a spacing of 0 with a spacing of 0.1, you'll notice the 0.1 kerning ends up being all over the place.

Comment: For future reference, there's a better answer to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65254013/2288578).

Answer (score 12):

I know this was answered a while back, but I needed a solution that had letter spacing and maintained the angular offsets.

I modified radzi's code to accomplish this:

```
function imagettftextSp($image, $size, $angle, $x, $y, $color, $font, $text, $spacing = 0)
{        
    if ($spacing == 0)
    {
        imagettftext($image, $size, $angle, $x, $y, $color, $font, $text);
    }
    else
    {
        $temp_x = $x;
        $temp_y = $y;
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++)
        {
            imagettftext($image, $size, $angle, $temp_x, $temp_y, $color, $font, $text[$i]);
            $bbox = imagettfbbox($size, 0, $font, $text[$i]);
            $temp_x += cos(deg2rad($angle)) * ($spacing + ($bbox[2] - $bbox[0]));
            $temp_y -= sin(deg2rad($angle)) * ($spacing + ($bbox[2] - $bbox[0]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to see you gave back to the Stack Overflow community with this answer. Good show +1

Answer (score 9):

Just to complete pidalia's answer (which is the best) to avoid some trouble with special char (like "é" or "à")

```
static function imagettftextSp($image, $size, $angle, $x, $y, $color, $font, $text, $spacing = 0) {
    if ($spacing == 0) {
        imagettftext($image, $size, $angle, $x, $y, $color, $font, $text);
    } else {
        $temp_x = $x;
        $temp_y = $y;
        //to avoid special char problems
        $char_array = preg_split('//u',$text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        foreach($char_array as $char) {
            imagettftext($image, $size, $angle, $temp_x, $temp_y, $color, $font, $char);
            $bbox = imagettfbbox($size, 0, $font, $char);
            $temp_x += cos(deg2rad($angle)) * ($spacing + ($bbox[2] - $bbox[0]));
            $temp_y -= sin(deg2rad($angle)) * ($spacing + ($bbox[2] - $bbox[0]));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

GD doesn't support kerning, so you'll have to do it manually. Personally, I wrote a function that would write each letter separately. I can't find it right now, but it's something along the lines of:

```
function drawText(&$image, $text, $fgColor, $font, $fgColor, 
                   $fontSize = 14, $kerning = 0, $x = 0, $y = 0) {
    $letters = explode('', $text);

    foreach ($letters as $n => $letter) {
        $bbox = imagettftext($image, $fontSize, 0, $x, $y, $fgColor, $font, $letter);
        $x += $bbox[2] + $kerning;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all the answers here and none seems to do a decent job. If you draw the bounding box, this is what happens:

[image]

Clearly they are not evenly spaced. It appears that the bounding box, returned by `imagettftext()` and `imagettfbbox()`, only tells you what is drawn. This might seem enough, but it isn't, because of [font kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning). This means that even when you say a letter should be draw at `(x,y)`, that that will not be one of the coordinates of the bounding box. A correction for kerning is needed.
[image]

I botched together this code for horizontal text:

```
function getBBoxW($bBox)
{
  return $bBox[2] - $bBox[0];
}


function imagettftextSpacing($image, $size, $x, $y, $color, $font, $text, $spacing = 0)
{
    $testStr = 'test';
    $testW   = getBBoxW(imagettfbbox($size, 0, $font, $testStr));
    foreach (mb_str_split($text) as $char)
    {
        $fullBox = imagettfbbox($size, 0, $font, $char . $testStr);
        imagettftext($image, $size, 0, $x - $fullBox[0], $y, $color, $font, $char);
        $x += $spacing + getBBoxW($fullBox) - $testW;
    }
}
```

The results are much better. Note that the `$testStr` can have any value.

Here's an example of the result, the first line is normal text, the second line has a negative spacing:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try this function:

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(500,200);
$text = "Text to print";
$text_color=imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255);
$font_size = 18;
$space = 8;
$font = "path_to_font/arial.ttf";
$x=20;
$y=20;
for ($i = 0; $i <strlen($text); $i++){
   $arr = imagettftext ($image, $font_size,0, $x, $y, $text_color, $font, $text{$i});
   $x = $arr[4]+$space;
}
imagejpeg($image);
destroyimage($image);
```