# Aligning php Generated Image dynamic text in center

Tags: php, imagettftext

i want to align the text generated on the image to the center of the image. for the moment, i dont know if it is possible to align it. below is the code.

```
$im = @imagecreatefromjpeg('poloroid.jpg');

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
//imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
//$text = 'John...';
$fbid = $_POST["id"]; 
$text = $_POST["want"];
$fb_email =$_POST["email"];
$fb_name=$_POST["name"];

$uploads_dir = 'uploaded_files/';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'verdana.ttf';

//image file name
//$name ="$fbid.png";
$name = $uploads_dir.$fbid.".png"; //this saves the image inside uploaded_files folder

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0,  25, 126, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 25, 125, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
//imagepng($im);
imagepng($im,$name,9);
imagedestroy($im);
```

thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 41):

```
$im = @imagecreatefromjpeg('poloroid.jpg');

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
//imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
//$text = 'John...';
$fbid = $_POST["id"]; 
$text = $_POST["want"];
$fb_email =$_POST["email"];
$fb_name=$_POST["name"];

$uploads_dir = 'uploaded_files/';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'verdana.ttf';
$font_size = 20;
$angle = 45;

//image file name
//$name ="$fbid.png";
$name = $uploads_dir.$fbid.".png"; //this saves the image inside uploaded_files folder

// Get image Width and Height
$image_width = imagesx($im);  
$image_height = imagesy($im);

// Get Bounding Box Size
$text_box = imagettfbbox($font_size,$angle,$font,$text);

// Get your Text Width and Height
$text_width = $text_box[2]-$text_box[0];
$text_height = $text_box[7]-$text_box[1];

// Calculate coordinates of the text
$x = ($image_width/2) - ($text_width/2);
$y = ($image_height/2) - ($text_height/2);

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, $font_size, 0, $x, $y+1, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
//imagepng($im);
imagepng($im,$name,9);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: i used this code. but then the images not the same position due to the difference in width. correct?

Comment: I didn't understand, please be more specific.

Comment: The line that calculates text bounding box height should be:     $text_height = $text_box[7]-$text_box[1]; - the code above incorrectly calculates it as 0. Sadly I'm not allowed to edit single characters...

Comment: Answer edited per the above comment from @John. Also added reference to `imagettfbbox()` documentation that justifies this change.

Comment: The above code was not centering properly for me. I changed $text_width to: $text_width = abs($text_box[4] - $text_box[0]) + 10; and $text_height = $text_box[7]-$text_box[1]; and also set $angle = 0; and then everything was centering correctly. Hope it helps someone else!

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php), the `x`, `y` coordinates represent the coordinates of the baseline start point so this will not center it

Answer (score 28):

You can use [stil/gd-text](https://github.com/stil/gd-text) class. Disclaimer: I am the author.

```
<?php
use GDText\Box;
use GDText\Color;

$im = @imagecreatefromjpeg('poloroid.jpg');

$textbox = new Box($im);
$textbox->setFontSize(20);
$textbox->setFontFace('verdana.ttf');
$textbox->setFontColor(new Color(0, 0, 0)); // black
$textbox->setTextShadow(
    new Color(0, 0, 0, 80), // black color, but 60% transparent
    0,
    -1 // shadow shifted 1px to top
);
$textbox->setBox(
    0,  // distance from left edge
    0,  // distance from top edge
    imagesx($im), // textbox width, equal to image width
    imagesy($im)  // textbox height, equal to image height
);

// now we have to align the text horizontally and vertically inside the textbox
// the texbox covers whole image, so text will be centered relatively to it
$textbox->setTextAlign('center', 'center');
// it accepts multiline text
$textbox->draw($text);

$uploads_dir = 'uploaded_files/';
//image file name
//$name ="$fbid.png";
$name = $uploads_dir.$fbid.".png"; //this saves the image inside uploaded_files folder
imagepng($im, $name, 9);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Demonstration:

[image: demo]

Comment: Excellent using it

Comment: Awesome. It's very easy to use. Nice documentation.

Comment: Hey, this works great.  Any way to automatically make the font size increase until the font fills the full width?  For example if I am making a logo generator that wants the word "example" to fill the full width - specified padding?

Comment: @smartrahat How do I set multiple paragraphs? Like how will I know at which coordinate the first paragraph has an end and set the box size accordingly for the 2nd para and onwards? I tried to tag the author but somehow it doesn't link ):

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your code a little:

```
function ImageTTFCenter($image, $text, $font, $size, $angle = 45) 
{
    $xi = imagesx($image);
    $yi = imagesy($image);

    $box = imagettfbbox($size, $angle, $font, $text);

    $xr = abs(max($box[2], $box[4]));
    $yr = abs(max($box[5], $box[7]));

    $x = intval(($xi - $xr) / 2);
    $y = intval(($yi + $yr) / 2);

    return array($x, $y);
}

$im = @imagecreatefromjpeg('poloroid.jpg');

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
//imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
//$text = 'John...';
$fbid = $_POST["id"]; 
$text = $_POST["want"];
$fb_email =$_POST["email"];
$fb_name=$_POST["name"];

$uploads_dir = 'uploaded_files/';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'verdana.ttf';

//image file name
//$name ="$fbid.png";
$name = $uploads_dir.$fbid.".png"; //this saves the image inside uploaded_files folder

list($x, $y) = ImageTTFCenter($im, $text, $font, 20)
// Add some shadow to the4 text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, $x, $y+1, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, $x, $y, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
//imagepng($im);
imagepng($im,$name,9);
imagedestroy($im);
```

The `ImageTTFCenter` function will find the center coordinates of you image which you will tell `imagettftext`

Comment: it aligns the starting of the text in the middle but not centering the text. do you understand what i mean?

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach ($user as $key=>$value){    
    $bb = imagettfbbox($value['font-size'],0,$fontname,$value['name']);    
    $WW = abs($bb[2]-$bb[0]);    
    $XX = ($value['XPos']+$WW);    
    $HH = abs($bb[5]-$bb[3]);    
    $HH +=1;
    $HHH += $HH;
    imagettftext($im, $value['font-size'], 0, $value['XPos'],   $value['YPos'], $color[$value['color']], $fontname, $value['name']);  
    $HHH += 1;
    $WIDE = abs($bb[2]-$bb[0]);  
    $endpoint=$value['XPos']+$WIDE;  
    $bb2 = imagettfbbox($value['font-size'],0,$fontname,$value['name']);  
    $WW2 = abs($bb2[2]-$bb2[0]);     
    $x2pos= $endpoint-$WW2;    
    imagettftext($im, $value['font-size'], 0, $x2pos, $value['YPos'], $color[$value['color']], $fontname, $value['name']);
}
```