# PHP imagecopy & imagecopymerge changing background from transparent to black

Tags: php, gd

I am copying one image and placing over second image, second image is transparent in background. While copying background of second image is converted to black. Even if i display image just after initializing image from file, it gives me black background. Please help..

```
<?php  

header('Content-type:image/png'); 

$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('eye.png');  

$watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);  

$watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);  

$image = imagecreatetruecolor($watermark_width, $watermark_height);  

$image = imagecreatefrompng('img.png');  

$size = getimagesize('img.png');  

$dest_x = $size[0] - $watermark_width - 5;  

$dest_y = $size[1] - $watermark_height - 5;  

imagecopyresampled($image, $watermark, 5, 5, 0,0,55 ,55, $watermark_width, $watermark_height);  
//imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, 5, 5, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 50);  

imagejpeg($image);  

imagedestroy($image);  

imagedestroy($watermark);  
?>
```

Comment: can you post your images? iam checking your problem.

Comment: Possibly a dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010758/black-background-on-gif-instead-of-transparency-in-php-using-imagegif/17016252#17016252

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the function

```
imagejpeg($image);
```

and add

```
imagealphablending($image, false); 
imagesavealpha($image,true);
imagepng($image);
```