# Prevent Gmail from caching images in newsletter

Tags: image, caching, proxy, gmail

Since December Gmail is caching all images.

Now dynamic images e.g. countdowns won't work properly. Once the image is cached the timer will show the time as the image was cached by google and won't update itself.

I've found a fix (and for those who want to help a further explanation): http://blog.movableink.com/real-time-content-and-re-open-tracking-return-to-gmail/

Now my problem: What do I have to do?

I tried adding "no-cache" and "max-age=0" to my header but Gmail is still caching it.

Here is my full header

```
header( 'Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s' ) . ' GMT' );
header( 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0' );
header( 'Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false );
header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );
```

I've also tried using only "no-cache" and "max-age" and other combinations as well, nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried just `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0");` and nothing else? I think the rest of the headers might be confusing Gmail.

Comment: Oh hi :)
Yeah, I'm pretty sure, but I'll try that again and this time on two several gmail accounts. One of mine can't even show schema actions in the subjectline o_O I will post my whole code after that if it's still not working.

Comment: Any updates on this? Would love to know if this worked.

Comment: Any update on whether it resolved?

Comment: I found out a solution and answered it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40569195/4312466