# PHP GIF generator got different result on Linux server and XAMPP on Windows

Tags: php, image, fonts, gif, animated-gif

I was following the example online to generate GIF timer for email (so JavaScript is not a choice). The following links are the example that I have read, with all of them tackling the problem in a similar way.

https://litmus.com/community/learning/27-how-to-add-a-countdown-timer-to-your-email

http://seanja.com/secret/countdown/

[Countdown Timer Image GIF in Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593420/countdown-timer-image-gif-in-email)

So I decided to change a bit of the [example code of the first link](https://github.com/Omgitsonlyalex/EmailCountdown). I was changing the time to compare and the font used in the counter to [Courier Prime](http://quoteunquoteapps.com/courierprime/) , which is a monospaced font so that the width of the timer won't change.

And the problem is the font.

This is the GIF I generated on XAMPP of my windows 7 PC:

[image]

And this is the GIF I generated on CentOS Apache server:

[image]

The image is cropped as the width of the font is wrong and overflows the background image. All codes, font files and background image is just a direct copy from my PC to the CentOS server.

Here is the code for generating the animated GIF after my changes:

```
//Leave all this stuff as it is
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Hong_Kong');
    include app_path().'/GIFEncoder.class.php';
    include app_path().'/php52-fix.php';
    $time = $time;
    $future_date = new DateTime(date('r',strtotime($time)));
    $time_now = time();
    $now = new DateTime(date('r', $time_now));
    $frames = array();
    $delays = array();


    // Your image link
    $image = imagecreatefrompng('./images/countdown.png');

    $delay = 100;// milliseconds

    $font = array(
        'size'=>23, // Font size, in pts usually.
        'angle'=>0, // Angle of the text
        'x-offset'=>3, // The larger the number the further the distance from the left hand side, 0 to align to the left.
        'y-offset'=>30, // The vertical alignment, trial and error between 20 and 60.
        'file'=>'./Courier Prime.ttf', // Font path
        'color'=>imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0), // RGB Colour of the text
    );
    if($future_date < $now)
        return "error!"; //this is impossible, but just for safety.
    for($i = 0; $i <= 60; $i++){

        $interval = date_diff($future_date, $now);

        // Open the first source image and add the text.
        $image = imagecreatefrompng('./images/white.png'); //this is just a white background with correct width and height
        $day    = $interval->format('%a');
        $hour   = $interval->format('%H');
        $minute = $interval->format('%I');
        $second = $interval->format('%S');
        $text = sprintf('%3d:%02d:%02d:%02d', $day, $hour, $minute, $second);

        imagettftext ($image , $font['size'] , $font['angle'] , $font['x-offset'] , $font['y-offset'] , $font['color'] , $font['file'], $text );
        ob_start();
        imagegif($image);
        $frames[]=ob_get_contents();
        $delays[]=$delay;
        $loops = 0;
        ob_end_clean();

        $now->modify('+1 second');
    }

    //expire this image instantly
    header( 'Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT' );
    header( 'Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s' ) . ' GMT' );
    header( 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' );
    header( 'Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false );
    header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );
    $gif = new AnimatedGif($frames,$delays,$loops);
    $gif->display();
```

Any idea on what's the possible reason of causing this?

Comment: Can we see the font painting code in your question please? Links are OK for reference, but we like to see a question that will survive if the links break - and folks prefer not to go off fetching stuff. Make life easy for your readers `:-)`

Comment: I don't mind placing the code here, but it is quite long and I have no idea where is it related to the current problem, so I prefer a link instead of pasting it here. Or should I add it?

And I thought github should be safe enough? If I need to consider dead link of github, I need to worry about stack overflow too.

Comment: Github won't go down, but people delete/move their repos. Can you just copy the relevant bit? Leave the link in, so people can still go visit. (Most of the code in that repo is nearly unreadable anyway, since the author has stripped out indentation. Hopefully in your own code you have added it back in!).