# Countdown timer gif in email using javascript NOT php

Tags: javascript, email, countdowntimer

I want to create a countdown timer to be used in email campaigns, it has to be done as a gif due to email browsers. Every method recommends using PHP, I would prefer to use Javascript because I have issues with PHP on my server. Is there anyway of making this with javascript?

Remember has to be gif, has to be for emails, not just working on a webpage.

The page here is good but offers php as the solution [Countdown Timer Image GIF in Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593420/countdown-timer-image-gif-in-email)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is this node.js app:

https://github.com/Nooshu/node-countdown-gif

It uses URL parameters

e.g. `?time=2049-09-24T20:35&name=ex1`

[image]