# PHP imagettfbbox gives different result when i'm trying to find text length and sum of char length

Tags: php, gd

I have a string with font and i need to find it's width, and then width of each char in this string, I'm using GD lib `imagettfbbox` for this, but it always gives me different result in the end.

```
$text="some random text";
$info=imagettfbbox(18,0,'/var/www/html/ARIAL.TTF',$text);
$text_width=$info[2]-$info[0];

$text_width_by_chars=0;
for($i=0;$i<strlen($text); $i++){
    $char=$text[$i];
    $info=imagettfbbox(18,0,'/var/www/html/ARIAL.TTF',$char);
    $char_width=$info[2]-$info[0];
    $text_width_by_chars+=$char_width;
}
echo $text_width.' '.$text_width_by_chars;
```

It happens to all fonts doesnt metter if `$info[0]` posetive or negative or 0, the differance is always around `strlen($text)` but not exactly, i've tried to find out if i can mutiply char width to some multiplier but it doesn't work, it's always around `0.91`.
Why does it happen? And how can i prevent this so in the end `$text_width` and `$text_width_by_chars` become equal?

Comment: I think it's all about kerning (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning). TTF file contains character pairs, that are different in width than each character separately.

Comment: Could also be some sort of automatic letter-spacing …?

Comment: @misorude how can i fix it? i want them to be equal

Comment: If it is due to anything like letter-spacing, then you can only try and figure out a common factor yourself, I think. Or use your own function to write text into the image, that lets you specify the letter-spacing, by actually drawing each letter individually to begin with - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926613/php-imagettftext-letter-spacing